# Find the starting indices of all occurrences of the pattern in the string - KMP algorithm follow-up

Tags: javascript, algorithm, programming-challenge, ecmascript-6

**The task**

was initially solved [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/221359/find-the-starting-indices-of-all-occurrences-of-the-pattern-in-the-string), but was too buggy:

> Given a string and a pattern, find the starting indices of all
>   occurrences of the pattern in the string. For example, given the
>   string "abracadabra" and the pattern "abr", you should return [0, 7].

**My solution**

Tried to solve it using [KMP-algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm):

```
function findStartingIndex(T, pattern) {
  if (pattern.length > T.length) { return []; }

  let next = 0;
  const res = [];

  const check = i => {
    for (let j = 1; j < pattern.length; j++) {
      if (next <= i && T[i + j] === pattern[0]) { next = i + j - 1; }
      if (T[i + j] !== pattern[j]) { return false; }
    }
    if (next <= i) { next = i + pattern.length - 1; }
    return true;
  };

  for (let i = 0; i < T.length; i++) {
    if (i + pattern.length > T.length) { return res; }
    if (T[i] === pattern[0] && check(i)) { res.push(i); }
    i = next;
  }
  return res;
}
```

Comment: Did you write automated tests? Which are your test cases? As you saw in the previous question, a single test case is not enough. If you only had this single test case, the expression `(() => [0, 7])` would satisfy all test cases, even though it is clearly wrong.

Comment: @RolandIllig Nope, I didn't write automated tests. But maybe I should in the future. I only tested some cases that I thought were critical: `abracadabra | abr`, `banana | a`, `12121212 | 1212`, `1111 | 1`

Answer (score 2):

A quick review;

- This tends to find more than 1 index, `findStartingIndex` -> `findStartingIndexes`
- In KMP, `T` is a lookup table, not the source string
- If you used the `while` statement proposed by Wikipedia, you would not need the first `if` statement
- In KMP, they use a lookup table, your code does not
- You have a tendency to one line `if` statements, it hampers readability
- Your code does not actually work `findStartingIndex("abracadabra","abr")` goes into an infinite loop, `next` doesn't get updated, and so keeps getting reset to `2`
- I wrote a counter proposal, it does use a bit of optimization but it does not use a search table like KMP, and is in my opinion far more understandable/readable

```js
function findStartingIndexes(haystack, needle){
  
  const needleLength = needle.length;
  const searchSpace = haystack.length - needleLength;
  const indexes = [];
  let position = 0;
  
  while(position <= searchSpace){
    if(haystack[position] == needle[0] &&
      haystack.slice(position, position + needleLength) == needle) {
          indexes.push(position);
      }
    position++;
  }
  return indexes;
}

function findStartingIndex(T, pattern) {
  if (pattern.length > T.length) { return []; }

  let next = 0;
  const res = [];

  const check = i => {
    for (let j = 1; j < pattern.length; j++) {
      if (next <= i && T[i + j] === pattern[0]) { next = i + j - 1; }
      if (T[i + j] !== pattern[j]) { return false; }
    }
    if (next <= i) { next = i + pattern.length - 1; }
    return true;
  };

  for (let i = 0; i < T.length; i++) {
    if (i + pattern.length > T.length) { return res; }
    if (T[i] === pattern[0] && check(i)) { res.push(i); }
    i = next;
  }
  return res;
}

//Infinite loop ;(
//console.log("[0,2]",JSON.stringify(findStartingIndex("abracadabra","abr")));

console.log("[0,2]",JSON.stringify(findStartingIndexes("ababab","abab")));
console.log("[]", JSON.stringify(findStartingIndexes("","abab")));
console.log("[0,7]",JSON.stringify(findStartingIndexes("abracadabra","abr")));
```